# Sum of Measures of Two Subsets = Sum of Measures of Their Union & Intersection

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

I have this solution to a problem in measure theory, I am posting it here to check my basic understanding:

> Let $(X, \mathscr A, \mu)$ be measure space with $A, B \in \mathscr A$, show that
>   $$\mu(A) + \mu(B) = \mu(A \cup B) + \mu ( A \cap B).$$

I would like to solve this problem by presenting three cases:

(1) If $A$ and $B$ are disjoint, $A \cap B = \emptyset$:

$$\begin{align}
A + B &= (A \cup B) \tag{a}\\
\therefore \ \mu(A) + \mu(B) &= \mu (A \cup B) + 0 \tag{b}\\
&= \mu (A \cup B) + \mu (\emptyset) \tag{c}\\
&= \mu (A \cup B) + \mu(A \cap B) \tag{d}\\
\end{align}$$

(2) If $A$ is proper subset of $B$, $A \subset B$:

$$\begin{align}
B &= A \cup B \tag{a}\\
\therefore \mu(B) &= \mu (A \cup B)\tag{b}\\
A &= A \cap B \tag{c}\\
\therefore \mu(A) &= \mu (A \cap B)\tag{d}\\
\therefore \   \mu(A) + \mu(B)&= \mu (A \cup B) + \mu(A \cap B)\tag{e}\\
\end{align}$$

(3) If A intersects B, $A \cap B \neq \emptyset$,

$$\begin{align}
A \cup B &= (A + B) - (A \cap B)\tag{a}\\
\therefore \ \mu(A \cup B) &= \mu(A) + \mu(B) - \mu (A \cap B)\tag{b}\\
\mu(A \cup B) + \mu (A \cap B)&= \mu(A) + \mu(B) \tag{c}\\
\mu(A) + \mu(B) &= \mu(A \cup B) + \mu (A \cap B) \tag{d}\\
\end{align}$$

Here is my question: Am I making invalid conclusions by jumping from (1a) to (1b), from (2a) to (2b), from (2c) to (2d), etc.? Do let me know if you have a more *elegant* solution.

Thank you for your time and effort.

Answer (score 7):

(1) is flawed because $+$ is not defined on sets (at least in terms of this problem you're only using: union, intersection and complement (noting that set-difference can be written in terms of complements and intersections)). However (1b)- (1c) are true and follow from (1b) which is true by definition of measure and the fact that the sets are disjoint.

Jump (2a) to (2b): If $A$ is a proper subset of $B$, then $A = A \cup B$ is not true to begin with, because it's proper to begin with, which means there exists $b \in B$ such that $b \notin A$. **If** that were true however, the step from (2a) to (2b) would work, because the sets are equal, i.e., if $A = B$, then $\mu(A) = \mu(B)$ is true. Same reasoning holds from (2c) to (2d).

(3) is flawed for the same reason (1) is flawed. Once you have (3b), you can't necessarily go to (3c) if some of these measures are infinite, in particular $\mu(A \cap B)$. (3c) to (3d) is definitely true.

---

Here is an alternate approach:

**Proof**: Observe that $A = (A \setminus B) \cup (A \cap B)$ and thus $$\mu(A) = \mu\big(  (A \setminus B) \cup (A \cap B) \big) = \mu(A \setminus B) + \mu(A \cap B).$$ Observe that $B = (B \setminus A) \cup (A \cap B)$ and thus $$\mu(B) = \mu \big( (B \setminus A) \cup (A \cap B) \big) = \mu(B \setminus A) + \mu(A \cap B).$$ Now notice that
            \begin{align*}
    \mu(A) + \mu(B) &= \mu(A \setminus B) + \mu(A \cap B) + \mu(B \setminus A) + \mu(A \cap B) \\
    &= \mu(A \cap B) + \mu \big( (A \setminus B) \cup (B \setminus A) \cup (A \cap B) \big) \\
    &= \mu(A \cap B) + \mu \big( (A \cup B) \setminus (A \cap B) \cup (A \cap B) \big) \\
    &= \mu(A \cap B) + \mu(A \cup B).
   \end{align*}

Comment: Oh, never mind about my logic, I guess I messed up with probability. I am still reading yours word by word, line by line. I love very much for line-by-line analysis, since you are dealing with a slowpoke here. In the meantime, since your bio mentioned that you are interested in algebra, have you ever seen this posting, which didn't get any meaningful response? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1115726/showing-g-zrg-isomorphic-to-autrg Are you familiar with the terms? I tried posting it in PhysicsForum & Quora, but I still did not get useful hints. Do let me know & thanks again and again.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the terms, but I'll take a look at it within the next week. I'm familiar with algebra, so I should be able to give you some feedback.

Comment: Take your time & thanks in advance. I have flipped (2a) to (2c) as you suggested. Out of 3 cases, I think (2) is the only correct one. Thanks again.

Comment: (2) is correct, (1) is correct from (1b) to (1c) and (3) is the one that takes the most work.

Comment: Not trying to repair my bruised ego, but I am wondering if there is any way to rescue (1a) with something legal? I used that because I saw something similar like that, but not sure now. Thanks.

Comment: Well you don't need (1a) at all in this case. (1b) is true and then you just go from there. (1b) is true because $A$ and $B$ are disjoint, so by definition of measure we can split the union up.

Comment: Is this the same with interior measure?I mean why is the sum of the interior measure of union and intersection of two nonempty sets is less than the sum of the interior measure every sets?

Answer (score 6):

**A more elegant solution:**

Define
$$
A_1 = A \cap B\\
A_2 = A \setminus A_1\\
A_3 = B \setminus A_1
$$
Note that by the definition of these set operations, the $A_i$ are disjoint.  By the general properties of a measure, the $A_i$ are measurable.

What you are attempting to show, then, is that
$$
\mu(A_1 \cup A_2) + \mu(A_1 \cup A_3) = \mu(A_1) + \mu(A_1 \cup A_2 \cup A_3)
$$

Comment: Thanks. May I say that even though my solution is dumb but luckily there is no "illegal" jumping to conclusion? Thanks again.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure what "$A + B$" is supposed to mean in step 1(a)

Comment: I think I messed up with probability theorem! Glad somebody brought that up.