proof of a lemma about measures
Hi All: I am reading a proof of a lemma in a real analysis text. The lemma states the following:
If $G_1$ and $G_2$ are bounded open sets, then $m(G_1) + m(G_2) = m(G_1 \cup G_2) + m(G_1 \cap G_2)$.
I'm quite  familiar with the relation but I never saw a proof until now. The problem is that I am having trouble following a step in the proof. Does anyone know where I can find a proof of this.  I'd rather see if I can understand a different proof. This one is not to my liking. Thanks.

Share the proof you're having difficulties with. How can someone provide a different proof if they haven't seen the one you already have?

Hi J. Doe: That' a good point but it's pretty long and I'm not a whiz in latex. I will type it if that turns out to be necessary. The book is "Intro to Real Analysis" by David Sprecher. It's actually an extremely well done book ( I've only been reading different chapters. not in order ) But this particular proof is confusing because he refers to exercises and previous definitions and lemma from other chapters. So, I'm not even sure if typing it out would help ?

Try showing that $\chi_{G_1}(x) + \chi_{G_2}(x) = \chi_{G_1 \cup G_2}(x) + \chi_{G_1 \cap G_2}(x)$ for each $x$. See what happens in the cases 1) $x$ is in neither $G_1$ or $G_2$ or 2) $x$ is in exactly one of $G_1$ or $G_2$ but not both 3) $x$ is in both $G_1$ and $G_2$. Then integrate both sides with respect to $x$.
I write $\chi_S$ to mean the "characteristic function" of $S$, defined as $1$ if $x \in S$ and $0$ if $x \not \in S$. One of the first steps in the the construction of the Lebesgue integral is defining $\int \chi_S(x) d m(x)= m(S)$, so hopefully that's fine.
There is no need to restrict to open bounded sets unless you have a restricted definition of $m$. This proof actually works on all measure spaces for all measurable sets, with the understanding that $\infty + x = \infty$ for any $x \ne -\infty$.

Hi George. The author does it by starting off with $ m(G_{i}) = M(F_{i}) + M(G_{i}\F_{i})$  and then using $\epsilon$ arguments by making the latter term less than $\frac{\epsilon}{4}$. So, it sounds pretty different from your approach. I'll read your answer carefully and it will take me time to possibly absorb it. Thanks for your help.

unsure what $F_i$ or $M$ is. Are you using outer or inner regularity or something?

Oops. I put big M, when I meant small. My mistake. I meant $ m(F_{i}) + m(G_{i}\F_{i}) $. I was just trying to give a feel for what he's doing. $F_{i}$ is another set contained in $G_{i}$ and that slash notation means ( which I couldn't figure out how to do in latex ) the set $G_{i}$  without the $F_{i}$ inside it. But don't worry about this. I'd have to write out the whole thing for it to possibly make any sense. And, as I said above, it's more confusing because of the references to other chapters.

this sounds like the proof that $m$ is monotone rather than the proof of the "inclusion-exclusion principle" in the case of $n = 2$, which is what this is. Could you post a picture?

George: I found this which seems like it's along the lines of your answer. I will combine yours with this one and hopefully understand it. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1133835/sum-of-measures-of-two-subsets-sum-of-measures-of-their-union-intersection

George: I found your email address so I'm deleting above and will send you the scanned pages late tonight or tomorrow. thanks for your interest. It's much appreciated.
